# How to access and increase 'rx2.buffer-size' in RxJava 2?

Tags: rx-java2, rx-android

In [http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/javadoc/io/reactivex/Observable.html) it is stated:

> The Observable's operators, by default, run with a buffer size of 128 elements (see Flowable.bufferSize(), that can be overridden globally via the system parameter rx2.buffer-size.

My question is, how can I access and set `rx2.buffer-size`? If I do:

```
import io.reactivex.Completable;
import io.reactivex.Flowable;
import io.reactivex.Observable;
import io.reactivex.Scheduler;
import io.reactivex.Single;
import io.reactivex.disposables.CompositeDisposable;
import io.reactivex.schedulers.Schedulers;
import io.reactivex.subjects.BehaviorSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.PublishSubject;
import io.reactivex.subjects.Subject;
import io.reactivex.*;
```

...followed by:

```
Integer bufferSize = rx2.buffer-size;
```

I am informed by Studio that:

- Unused import statement (for `import io.reactivex.*;`)
- Cannot resolve symbol 'rx2'
- Cannot resolve symbol 'size'

How can I override the system parameter `rx2.buffer-size`?

My project is using

```
io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxandroid/2.0.1
io.reactivex.rxjava2/rxjava/2.1.11
```

Answer (score 5):

Try :

```
Integer bufferSize = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("rx2.buffer-size"))
```

To set a new value :

```
System.setProperty("rx2.buffer-size", 2048)
```

Comment: Note that you have to do this before the RxJava classes are initialized.

Comment: @suenda Thanks!

`Integer bufferSize = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("rx2.buffer-size"))`

should be instead:

`Integer bufferSize = Integer.parseInt(System.getProperty("rx2.buffer-size", "42"))`

Where the `42` is a default value; otherwise a null will be returned (and Bad Things Happen) if the property is not _already_ set.

Also, `2048` needs to be a string, not an integer:

`System.setProperty("rx2.buffer-size", "2048")`