# Avoiding same-pool deadlocks when using Flowable in Reactive Extensions

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2, deadlock

While subscribing to a Reactive Extensions `Flowable` stream, I noticed the stream halts/hangs (no more future items are emitted, and no error is returned) after 128 items have been returned.

```
val download: Flowable<DownloadedRecord> = sensor.downloadRecords()
download
    .doOnComplete { Log.i( "TEST", "Finished!" ) }
    .subscribe(
        { record ->
            Log.i( "TEST", "Got record: ${record.record.id}; left: ${record.recordsLeft}" )
        },
        { error ->
            Log.i( "TEST", "Error while downloading records: $error" )
        } )
```

Most likely, this is related to Reactive Extensions. I discovered [the default buffer size of `Flowable` is set to 128](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html); unlikely to be a coincidence.

While trying to understand what is happening, I ran into the following documentation on [`Flowable.subscribeOn`](http://reactivex.io/RxJava/2.x/javadoc/io/reactivex/Flowable.html#subscribeOn-io.reactivex.Scheduler-boolean-).

> If there is a `create(FlowableOnSubscribe, BackpressureStrategy)` type source up in the chain, it is recommended to have `requestOn` false to avoid **same-pool deadlock** because requests may pile up behind an eager/blocking emitter.

Although I do not quite understand what a *same-pool deadlock* is in this situation, it looks like something similar is happening to my stream.

**1. What is a *same-pool deadlock* in Reactive Extensions?** What would be a minimal code sample to recreate it (on Android)?

Currently at a loss, I tried applying `.subscribeOn( Schedulers.io(), false )` before `.subscribe`, without really understanding what this does, but my stream still locks up after 128 items have been emitted.

**2. How could I go about debugging this issue, and how/where can it be resolved?**

Comment: I rely on a `.window( )` in the stream which takes a `Flowable.create` as a boundary indicator, used to slice up upstream items into the eventual records to be downloaded. This seems as a likely candidate for something to go wrong. Currently investigating.

Comment: I [increased the default buffer size to 130](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52956589/590790), after which it hangs after 130 emitted records, confirming the problem is related to this parameter.

Comment: The root cause of my problem turned out _not_ to be a same-pool deadlock, [but rather a bug in RxJava](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues/6363). However, this question still makes sense, and the bugfix does not really answer it. Therefore, I will keep it around.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. What is a same-pool deadlock in Reactive Extensions?

RxJava uses single threaded executors in the standard schedulers. When a blocking or eager source is emitting items, it occupies this single thread and even though the downstream requests more, `subscribeOn` will schedule those requests behind the currently running/blocking code that then never gets notified about the new opportunities.

> What would be a minimal code sample to recreate it (on Android)?

Why would you want code that deadlocks?

> I tried applying .subscribeOn( Schedulers.io(), false )

What is your actual flow? You likely applied `subscribeOn` too far from the source and thus it has no effect. The most reliable is to put it right next to `create`.

> How could I go about debugging this issue, and how/where can it be resolved?

Putting `doOnNext` and `doOnRequest` at various places and see where signals disappear.

Comment: _"Why would you want code that deadlocks?"_ To understand it better. :) The equivalent of a picture says more than a thousand words.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava/issues?q=is%3Aissue+same+pool+deadlock+is%3Aclosed